# StackExchange API for people search on StackOverflow

Tags: stackexchange, stackexchange-api

I was trying to search people in StackOverflow using the StackExchange APIs. Is there a way to search people by the tags they have associated with there profile. Like LinkedIn API allows searching for "Java Programming" giving back people in 1st 2nd degree connection with Java or Programming in there profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it try..

- /tags/{tags}/topusers
- /tags/{tags}/top-answerers
- **/tags/{tags}/top-askers**

Not sure if API endpoint still available with V2.2.